# Java toString() printing issues

Tags: java

I am currently using an toString() method to print out an array list. It works but the output comes out all wonky in the console when it prints out. I was wondering is anyone would point out to me where i am going wrong or even direct me to a tutorial that would help better explain his type of formatting.

Method i am using:

rental number, release and releaseYear are all ints.
film , fname, studio are all strings

```
public String toString()
{
    //Returns a String
    return String.format("DVDDetails [%s |\t\t %s \t\t | \t\t %s  | %s | %s| %s| ]",rental, fFName, FAName, studio, releaseYear);
}
```

Comment: Can you provide an example of the output you get?

Comment: Edit your question to add more info like that. Then you can format it to look exactly how it does in your console.

Comment: @Takendarkk i am printing an arraylist and it all correctly laid out in the program but not when it prints out

Comment: Paste your output as code in the question. make sure it looks like what you get on your monitor

Comment: @Sean87  i have added it in to my question, the last three lines is how it looks in the console

Comment: The toString() method is for debugging. You shouldn't rely on it to produce a specific structured output. Write a separate method for that.

Comment: @EJP I did' t know that!!. As the minute it is the only way i am familiar with because it is the only way that has been mentioned in class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the `fFname` results in a string with varrying number of characters, it looks like that. The formater has no idea of the next line so the tab is only effective on its own line. you better off add spaces depending on the length of the string you have. count number of characters and add spaces. have a max value with the largest length of `fFname` and other strings values.

You can look in java documetns for inserting spaces in formatting. something like`"%-20s %s"`